# how to load external images for sphere texture unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, texture2d, virtual-tour

i'm trying to create a unity script that will generate a 360° visit and it must be managed by a web platform (where you upload your 360° images ) so my sphere in the unity script must load external images for the sphere texture. I found only how to load external images for texture2D. Help please 
I tried this script [script to load image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qtfbG.png)
and this is how it look [how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ReNJ.png)

Comment: That sounds pretty close to your goal...load your image into a Texture2D, use that Texture2D on a material, apply that material to a sphere...success? Have you made any attempts that demonstrate how this approach might not be viable?

Comment: you can check my script to load image

Comment: For your question code and your answer code, would you post them as text? We discourage code pasted as images, since that does not work with clipboards, screen-readers or search engines.

Answer (score 1):

it's solved now i can load external images from url to set in my sphere texture . this is the script [new script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHjCk.png)
and now this is how it [looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mIh8Z.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

The first step is correct with loading the image in to a `Texture2D` however you now need to assign that texture to the spheres material. There are someways to do that and one of them is this

```
//Assuming sphere is a reference to a GameObject with a renderer attached
//After loading image
sphere.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture = img;
```

This should replace the materials main texture with the image you loaded.